# Spring does not find WebApplicationInitializer when packaged in a fat Jetty jar

Tags: spring, jar, jetty

I am trying to create a single "FAT" jar of embedded Jetty and my code. Unfortunatly if I run from the jar I get this error: `No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`

If I unpack the jar it works just fine.

The question is can I run the app from the jar or does it have to be unpacked?

Here is a sample project and the steps to reproduce the issue:

> git clone https://github.com/steveliles/jetty-embedded-spring-mvc-noxml.git
>   cd jetty-embedded-spring-mvc-noxml
>   mvn clean install
>   cd target
>   java -jar jetty-noxml-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

You will get this output "...No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath...".

but if you do this:

> mkdir temp
>   cd temp
>   unzip jetty-noxml-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   java -cp . com.sjl.Main

This will work just fine.

So what can be done to make this work directly from the jar without unpacking it first?

== Update ==

The author of the project resolved the issue. The following code was needed to pickup webapps from a shaded jar:

```
   parser = new AnnotationParser() {

       @Override
       public void parse(Resource aDir, ClassNameResolver aResolver) throws Exception {
           if (aDir.isDirectory()) {
               super.parse(aDir, aResolver);
           } else {
               super.parse(aDir.getURI(), aResolver);
           }
       }
    };
```

See: https://github.com/steveliles/jetty-embedded-spring-mvc-noxml/commit/789663310b2fa2bdc0b101658275758a26cec229

Comment: You need to add the class containing the `main` method in a MANIFEST file in your jar.

Comment: The jar has this in the Manifest "Main-Class: com.sjl.Main" which is added by maven from https://github.com/steveliles/jetty-embedded-spring-mvc-noxml/blob/master/pom.xml line 98.

Comment: I added an update above. But the issue was resolved in this commit:  https://github.com/steveliles/jetty-embedded-spring-mvc-noxml/commit/789663310b2fa2bdc0b101658275758a26cec229

Comment: Good to hear. If you know the exact reason of the fix, you should add yourself an answer for others that may fall on the same issue.